# Access a page/service that exists on another server in ExtJS

Tags: json, url, extjs, proxy, combobox

I am presently working on two different linux boxes in the same network. Now I have my extjs javascript/front end code running on one linux box, while I have a web service and my database sitting on another linux box. Both these boxes have apache webserver and can function independently. Now when I fire/load my UI, I would be using a url which looks like

**http://server1/user/page.php** and when I fire up my web service(returns json data) I would be using a url of **http://server2/user/service.php**.

Now this service returns the options which have to loaded into the combo-box. Now, Extjs provides us with an option of using http-proxy to mention a url from where the options/data would be provided.

So, I believe, it has to make a call to that url and get the data from that service. But the wierd thing is, it does not even make a call to that address. Am I making a mistake with this?? I have been tracking all the ajax calls, but no call was made for this url. If I do remove the http address and just place it as service.php(for checking), then it makes a call to the address **http://server1/user/service.php** and returns a 404 not found error.

Could somebody point to the mistake that I am making.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, familiarize yourself with the concept and limitations of  [*Cross-site HTTP requests*](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control)
- Then, modify your JS code to use [ScriptTagProxy](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy) instead of HttpProxy

Comment: Amol, I did try it with ScriptTagProxy, but it still isn't working. The weird thing is, it does not even make a get/post call. I am not finding any request that goes to that webservice. Have you had this problem with Scripttagproxy before?

Comment: can you post your updated code pieces related to defining the proxies and store load calls (if autoload is false)

Comment: Hello Amol, I have made the required edits, could you please take a look now, thank you

Comment: Hey I figured it out. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know its working for you. Can you please consider posting your working snippets for community benefit?